# Creationist "canard" refutation type questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Let's just say that proponents of creationism and "intelligent design" have a ready stable of canards and distortions out there.  Would it be appropriate to post such canards here as questions, and then post the answer (as long as it adhered to biology).  For instance, let's take the ever popular canard of "Natural selection is based on circular reasoning: the fittest are those who survive, and those who survive are deemed fittest."

Answer (score 8):

It would be good to knock out those canard questions on Biology since we would be using actual biological science to refute and answer such questions.

And these topics come up in almost every class/subject in Biology...

Comment: I have a ready stable of them.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Would such questions not belong more on [SE Scientific Skepticism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Perhaps.  Actually, I have seen a few of them there already.  I just thought that a site that attracts professionals in the field of biology would get even more detailed and better replies.  :)